# How can you add mutation observer to a WebView2 control

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, webview2

I'm building a WinForms App that is using  WebView2 control
Is there an a way to inject some JavaScript maybe with a mutation observer to get the content of a div after an ajax call?

I think this could be done using ScriptNotify  in WebVeiw

My problem is I can inject a script but the control is returned back to WinForms before the JavaScript finishes

C#

```
        private async void webView21_NavigationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        StatusLabel.Text = "Page loaded";
       string Script = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Vb\Test\WebView2ControlWinForms\TestScript.js");

        await webView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(Script);

        // Stop here until last line finishesd;
        string res = await webView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(@"document.getElementById('res').innerHTML");
        var htmldecoded = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(res);
        richTextBox1.Text = htmldecoded;
    }
```

JavaScript

```
// JavaScript source code
var results = [];
let target = document.querySelector('.getblock')
let config = { childList: true }
let observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutationList, observer) {
    console.log("CONTENT CHANGED!")
    console.log(mutationList)
    console.log(observer)
    for (const mutation of mutationList) {
        if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
            console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
            results.push(mutation);
        }
        else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
            console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
        }
    }
    //json = JSON.stringify(results);
    //returnFunc(json);

    GetLinks();
    
})

observer.observe(target, config)

var el = document.querySelectorAll('.getblock span');
//var el = document.querySelectorAll('button');
var i;
alert("el is " + el.length + " Long");
for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    // alert("Click "+ i);
    el[i].click();
}

function GetLinks() {
    alert("Hello from GetLinks ")
    var el = document.querySelectorAll('.getblock  a');
    alert("Hello from GetLinks " + el.length);
    var i;
    var json;
    for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        results.push(el[i].href);
        json = JSON.stringify(results);
    }
    returnFunc(json);
}

function returnFunc(json) {
    var ele = document.getElementById('res');
    if (ele !== null) {
        ele.innerHTML = json
    } else {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.id = 'res';
        div.innerHTML = json
        document.body.appendChild(div);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling await on an ExecuteScriptAsync call will wait for the synchronous global script to execute or throw an unhandled exception. So any asynchronous JavaScript code like callbacks from setTimeout, promises, or a MutationObserver, will not be awaited by ExecuteScriptAsync. Or if there's any unhandled exception it will stop executing the injected script.

If you need to know about asynchronous JavaScript code completing, you can use [`CoreWebView2.WebMessageReceived`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.webmessagereceived?view=WebView2-dotnet-1.0.674-prerelease) and `chrome.webview.postMessage` to send a message from your script to your native code once the script is done.

If you want detailed error information in the case of an unhandled exception you can wrap your injected code in a try/catch block and examine any unhandled exceptions.

Comment: Are you saying to send / inject the JavaScript code with chrome.webview.postMessage when it has finished it will trigger CoreWebView2.WebMessageReceived? apart from the basic [gettingstarted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/winforms) are there any tutorials or examples of  how to do this?

Comment: Yes, exactly. In your native code subscribe to the WebMessageReceived event, then inject your script. The script at any point asynchronously or otherwise can call `chrome.webview.postMessage({ completed: true });` and you'll receive that object as JSON in WebMessageReceived.

The WebView2Sample app has sample code https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/blob/abd2b9b42e6a57c0a4472765d755c923c0ffb694/SampleApps/WebView2APISample/ScenarioWebMessage.html

Comment: I've been looking at the sample code It's looks like the native code is not C# maybe C++?  Using that as source could you show me how it is Done in C# or would that need a new thread?

Comment: There's no other examples or samples. You can open a new thread if you like.